# How do I know which Gatekeeper signature does my OS X app use?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, osx-gatekeeper

From a recent post by Apple:

> With the release of OS X Mavericks 10.9.5, the way that OS X
>   recognizes signed apps will change. Signatures created with OS X
>   Mountain Lion 10.8.5 or earlier (v1 signatures) will be obsoleted and
>   Gatekeeper will no longer recognize them. Users may receive a
>   Gatekeeper warning and will need to exempt your app to continue using
>   it. To ensure your apps will run without warning on updated versions
>   of OS X, they must be signed on OS X Mavericks 10.9 or later (v2
>   signatures).

How do I know if my app needs to be resigned?

Comment: I understand this only affects code signatures created with `codesign` not pkg installer signatures (`productsign`). Can you confirm this by any chance?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Code signing is black magic to me.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried it now and did not observe any change for the installer package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ codesign -dv Foo.app
Executable=/Applications/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
Identifier=com.example.Foo
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=915 flags=0x200(kill) hashes=37+5 location=embedded
Signature size=4169
Info.plist entries=30
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=1 rules=5 files=33 // ⬅︎ this is the line
Internal requirements count=1 size=228
```

For details see [Technical Note TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html), OS X Code Signing In Depth.